# 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse through my .xml file using glob and then use etree to add more code to my .xml. However, I keep getting an error when using `doc insert` that says object has no attribute insert. Does anyone know how I can effectively add code to my .xml?

```
from lxml import etree
path = "D:/Test/"
for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*/*.xml'):
    doc = etree.parse(xml_file)
    new_elem = etree.fromstring("""<new_code abortExpression=""
                        elseExpression=""
                        errorIfNoMatch="false"/>""")
doc.insert(1,new_elem)
new_elem.tail = "\n"
```

My original xml looks like this :

```
<data>
  <assesslet index="Test" hash-uptodate="False" types="TriggerRuleType" verbose="True"/>
</data>
```

And I'd like to modify it to look like this:

```
<data>
<assesslet index="Test" hash-uptodate="False" types="TriggerRuleType" verbose="True"/>
<new_code abortExpression="" elseExpression="" errorIfNoMatch="false"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `glob` call found any files? Your `doc.insert` is outside the for loop, so it would be on the last doc, or on an unitialized `doc` variable if the loop didn't find any file.

Comment: Nevermind, I just reproduced your error message without a loop. Your code structure is still weird, but that's not the issue.

Comment: @joanis yes, I was about to say, I had a print statement to see if that was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to extract the root from your document before you can start modifying it: modify `doc.getroot()` instead of `doc`.

This works for me:

```
from lxml import etree
xml_file = "./doc.xml"
doc = etree.parse(xml_file)
new_elem = etree.fromstring("""<new_code abortExpression=""
                            elseExpression=""
                            errorIfNoMatch="false"/>""")
root = doc.getroot()
root.insert(1, new_elem)
new_elem.tail="\n"
```

To print the results to a file, you can use `doc.write()`:

```
doc.write("doc-out.xml", encoding="utf8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Note the `xml_declaration=True` argument: it tells `doc.write()` to produce the `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?>` header.

Comment: hi @joanis, do I need to save the xml file at the end? I tried the code , and I don't get any errors, but my .xml isn't changed after executing.

Comment: Indeed, this just modifies the structure in memory. You'll need to write it back after.

Comment: it worked, thanks. Although, for some reason I lose the "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> at the top , which i forgot to show, although I don't know if it matters

Comment: See edit for how to print with the XML declaration.